# How to use scriptlets in HTMLOutput in Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm loading a modal dialog with:

```
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('File')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(1000)
    .setHeight(700);

 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
    .showModalDialog(html, 'My Page');
```

Now, in File.HTML, I want to load another HTML file with CSS settings, how do I do that?

I've tried including it as in `HtmlTemplate` using scriptlets but it doesn't work:

```
<?!= include('File'); ?>
```

EDIT:

I have defined the include function in code.gs:

```
function include (file) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file).evaluate().getContent();
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that you are using:

```
createHtmlOutputFromFile
```

instead of:

```
createTemplateFromFile
```

You need to create a template:

This is what you are seeing:

[image: Include with Dialog]

The scriptlet is not running, but being interpreted as text.

This is what you want to see:

[image: Include that works]

Here is how the code should be:

### Code.gs

```
// Use this code for Google Docs, Forms, or new Sheets.
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Dialog')
      .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
    .evaluate();//This is necessary

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}

function include(File) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(File).getContent();
};
```

### index.html

```
<?!= include('File'); ?>

Hello, world!
<input type="button" value="Close"
  onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
```

### File.html

```
<div>
    This is a test. it worked!
</div>
```

Basically, you need to change:

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
```

to:

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
```

Create a **TEMPLATE** from file.

And I also changed the code to this:

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

### Original answer:

`include` is not something like a `keyword` or a built in function.  You need to create a function in a `.gs` script file named `include`.

```
    function include(filename) {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
    };
```

Also, you can't mix the HTML Service and the UI Service.  I don't know if that's what you are trying to do, but I thought I'd mention it.

What you want to accomplish is describe in the documentation here:

[Documentation - Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript)

Comment: Thanks, please see my edit. I had defined include before in code.gs. It works well in a sidebar but when I open the modal dialog  it just types <?!= include('File'); ?>

Comment: Yep, that works, also with the new IFRAME mode.
Have to understand better the difference between Template and Output