# Posting a Google Sheet to a Google Site as an HTML table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

I have a Google Sheet with about six hundred rows of data. I want to be able to display and filter this spreadsheet as an HTML table and have it displayed to a Google Site. I have found this code online along with the 'Display' HTML which I have used.

However when I publish as a web app, I am only seeing the outline of my table but with no data in the rows. The outline of my table looks correct and contains the search filters I need, however there is no data appearing in the table.

Is there an issue with the code below?

```
 function myFunction() {

 }function doGet(e){

    var SHEET_ID=e.parameter.sheet_id

    var html=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Display')

    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('My Google Sheet ID')
    var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2')

    html.data=getRowsData(sheet,sheet.getDataRange(),1)

    return html.evaluate().setTitle('Log')

    Logger.log(getRowsData(sheet,sheet.getDataRange(),1))
   }

   
function include(filename){

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent()

}




function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex){

  columnHeadersRowIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range.getRowIndex()-1;
  var numColumns = range.getEndColumn() - range.getColumn() + 1;
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(columnHeadersRowIndex, range.getColumn(), 1, 
  numColumns);
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  return getObjects(range.getValues(),normalizeHeaders(headers));

}



function getObjects(data, keys) {
  var objects = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var object = {};
    var hasData = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
       var cellData = data[i][j];
       if (isCellEmpty(cellData)) {
          continue;
        }
        object[keys[j]] = cellData;
        hasData = true;
      }
      if (hasData) {
        objects.push(object);
      }
    }
    return objects;
  }



function normalizeHeaders(headers) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
    var key = normalizeHeader(headers[i]);
    if (key.length > 0) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
   }
   return keys;
}

function normalizeHeader(header) {
  var key ='';
  var upperCase = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
    var letter = header[i];
    if (letter == '' && key.length > 0) {
       upperCase = true;
       continue;
     }
     if (!isAlnum(letter)) {
       continue;
     }
     if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) {
       continue; // first character must be a letter
     }
     if (upperCase) {
        upperCase = false;
        key += letter.toUpperCase();
     } else {
       key += letter.toLowerCase();
     }
  }
  return key;
}



function isAlnum(char) {
  return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
    char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' ||
    isDigit(char);
}



function isDigit(char) {
  return char >= '0' && char <= '9';
}



function isCellEmpty(cellData) {
  return typeof(cellData) == 'string' && cellData == '';
}
```

Display.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
     <?!=include('Style')?>
  </head>

  <body>

<p></p>

<table id="dataTable" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">

<th width="10%">Employee Number</th>
<th width="15%">Name</th>
<th width="15%">Surname</th>
<th width="15%">EmpNo</th>
<th width="10%">Title</th>
<th width="15%">Div</th>
<th width="10%">Office</th>
<th width="10%">Form</th>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#eb8c00" align="center"><input type="text" 
id="EmployeeNumberSearchBox" onkeyup="SearchFunc()" 
placeholder="EmployeeNumber..." width="30"></td>
<td bgcolor="#eb8c00" align="center"><input type="text" 
id="NameSearchBox" 
onkeyup="SearchFunc()" placeholder="Name..." width="35"></td>
<td bgcolor="#eb8c00" align="center"><input type="text" id="SurnameSearchBox" 
onkeyup="SearchFunc()" placeholder="Surname..." width="35"></td>
<td bgcolor="#eb8c00" align="center"><input type="text" id="EmpNoSearchBox" 
onkeyup="SearchFunc()" placeholder="EmpNo..." width="35"></td>
<td bgcolor="#eb8c00" align="center"><input type="text" id="TitleSearchBox" 
onkeyup="SearchFunc()" placeholder="Title..." width="35"></td>

<td bgcolor="#eb8c00" align="center">
<select id="Div" onchange="SearchFunc();">
  <option value="">Div...</option>
  <option value="DOO">DOO</option>
  <option value="PIT">PIT</option>
  <option value="FID">FID</option>
  <option value="FIS">FIS</option>
  <option value="General">General</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
  <option value="IS">IS</option>
  <option value="SAS">SAS</option>
</select>
</td>

<td bgcolor="#eb8c00" align="center">
<select id="Office" onchange="SearchFunc();">
  <option value="">Office...</option>
  <option value="London">London</option>
  <option value="New York">New York</option>
  <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
  <option value="Eindhoven">Eindhoven</option>
  <option value="Lille">Lille</option>
  <option value="Vienna">Vienna</option>
  <option value="Copenhagen">Copenhagen</option>
</select>
</td>

<td bgcolor="#eb8c00" align="center"></td>


</tr>

<? for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++) {?>

<tr style="height:15px;">

<td align="center"><?=data[i]['Employee Number']?> </td>
<td align="left"><?=data[i]['Div']?> </td>
<td align="center"><?=data[i]['EmpNo']?> </td>
<td align="center"><?=data[i]['Name']?> </td>
<td align="center"><?=data[i]['Surname']?> </td>
<td align="center"><?=data[i]['Title']?> </td>
<td align="center"><?=data[i]['Office']?> </td>
<td align="center">
<a href="<?=data[i]['=ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(K1:K616, "Click here to complete 
Access Form"))']?>" target="_blank"><button>Open Form</button> 
</a>
</td>
</tr>

<? } ?>

</table>

  </body>

</html>
```

Style.Html

```
<style>

input[type=text] {

font-size: 12px; /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px; /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 3px; /* Add some space below the input */
  margin-top: 2px;

}

#EmployeeNumberSearchBox, #EmpNoSearchBox, #NameSearchBox, 
#SurnameSearchBox, #OfficeSearchBox, #TitleSearchBox {
text-align:center;
width:50%; 
}

#DivSearchBox{
text-align:center;
width:85%;
}


#dataTable {

  border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 14px; /* Increase font-size */
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#dataTable th{
text-align: center; /* Centre-align text */
background-color: #d04a02;
color: #ffffff
}

#dataTable td {
  padding: 3px 5px 2px 10px; 
}

#dataTable tr {
  /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}



button {

  background-color: #464646;
  border:none;
  padding: 3px 5px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;

  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  font-style: Bold;
  color: white;

 }

 button:hover {

   background-color: #eb8c00; /* Green */
   color: white;
   cursor:pointer;

 }


 select {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:35px;
    text-align-last:center;
  }

 </style>
```

Java.html

```
<script>


function SearchFunc() {
  var EmployeeNumberInput, DivInput, EmpNoInput, NameInput, 
  SurnameInput, OfficeInput, TitleInput,
  EmployeeNumberFilter, DivFilter, EmpNoFilter, NameFilter, 
  SurnameFilter, OfficeFilter, TitleFilter,
  table, tr, i,
  EmployeeNumberValue, DivValue, EmpNoValue, NameValue, 
  SurnameValue, OfficeValue, TitleValue;

  EmployeeNumberInput = document.getElementById("Employee Number");
  DivInput =  document.getElementById("Div");
  EmpNoInput =  document.getElementById("EmpNo");
  NameInput =  document.getElementById("Name");
  SurnameInput =  document.getElementById("Surname");
  TitleInput =  document.getElementById("Title"); 
  OfficeInput = document.getElementById("Office");

  EmployeeNumberFilter = EmployeeNumberInput.value.toUpperCase();
  DivFilter = DivInput.value.toUpperCase();
  EmpNoFilter = EmpNoInput.value.toUpperCase();
  NameFilter = NameInput.value.toUpperCase();
  SurnameFilter = SurnameInput.value.toUpperCase();
  TitleFilter = TitleInput.value.toUpperCase();
  OfficeFilter = OfficeInput.value.toUpperCase();


  table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");


  for (i = 2; i < tr.length; i++) {

    EmployeeNumberValue = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    DivValue = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    EmpNoValue = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    NameValue = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
    SurnameValue = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
    TitleValue = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[5];
    OfficeValue = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[6];


    if (EmployeeNumberValue) {
      if (EmployeeNumberValue.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf
      (EmployeeNumberFilter) > -1 
      && 
      DivValue.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(DivFilter) > -1 
      && 
      EmpNoValue.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(EmpNoFilter) > -1
      && 
      NameValue.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(NameFilter) > 
      -1
      && 
      SurnameValue.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(SurnameFilter) > -1
      && 
      TitleValue.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(TitleFilter) > -1)
      && 
      OfficeValue.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(OfficeFilter) > -1) {
  
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
   }
 }



function sortTable() {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
  switching = true;
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // Start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /* Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers): */
    for (i = 2; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      // Start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
     one from current row and one from the next: */
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      // Check if the two rows should switch place:
      if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done: */
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}




</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<?=` use `<?!=`

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets

> **Force-printing scriptlets**
>
> Force-printing scriptlets, which use the syntax `<?!= ... ?>`, are like printing scriptlets except that they avoid contextual escaping.
>
> Contextual escaping is important if your script allows untrusted user input. By contrast, you’ll need to force-print if your scriptlet’s output intentionally contains HTML or scripts that you want to insert exactly as specified.
>
> As a general rule, use printing scriptlets rather than force-printing scriptlets unless you know that you need to print HTML or JavaScript unchanged.

Related

- [How to use scriptlets in HTMLOutput in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27510858/1595451)